# How can I close the TextWriter stream on Windows XP successfully?

Tags: c#, .net, io, try-catch-finally

I have a code like the following one for working with a TextWriter stream.

```
TextWriter TR = new StreamWriter(@"")

try
{

    //Logic

}
catch (Exception exception)
{

    //Error Reporting

}
finally
{

    if (TR != null)
        TR.Close();

}
```

My .Net version is 4.0 and this code works properly on Windows 7 but it does not work properly in Windows XP!! It seems that the stream does not close and a number of buffers are not written to file! I have no idea! Can anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: Maybe not a direct solution but please also look at the `using` keyword for more elegant code :)

Comment: Detail "stream not closed" - can other code Open or Delete it ?

Comment: Looking at your code it sounds more the logic part that is at fault, and that its giving up before its done

Comment: As others have suggested, you should try to make your code more robust (e.g. by using `using`). As one more example, the `if (TR != null)` condition is never `false`, because you never reach that code if the ctor of `StreamWriter` above throws (unless of course you set it to `null` somewhere in the code you haven't shown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem isn't that the streams haven't closed, but rather than the streams may have been closed before they have written.
With most stream output you will need to Flush the output stream to ensure that the changes have been written before you Close it. If you don't, then unflushed data will be lost, which sounds very much like what you're seeing.

As Gerald suggested, I would also recommend the

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(@"")
{
    // ...

    writer.Flush();
}
```

format, because while it just achieves much the same as try{...}finally{...} it is a little more elegant, and slightly easier to get right.

Comment: Close() calls Dispose() and that calls Flush().

Comment: I have tested this approach too and the problem is still remained!